# The animation css / jquery does not restart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm starting to make css animations but in this job I could not restart the animation css and javascript for the .click work again --- what would be the most effective way to work this to upload content to each panel activating and deactivating all With cSS divs every time you order in jquery?

```
The css code is acompiled to less my own code start to the 6550 line
http://plnkr.co/edit/t4zFxM35sBKmmclGpRZ1?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

The image back button is not visible. Add the following css in style.css.

```
// Line no 6566, style.css
.back { 
z-index: 2;
}
```

Now the button is visible and so clickable. You can go ahead to develop your code.

**Tips:**
Use google chrome inspector to check your code. It's faster and easier.